# How to prevent removing notifications from the lock screen in Android L?

Tags: notifications, lock-screens, 5.0-lollipop

I can remove notifications on the lock screen without unlocking. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this is not possible.